# ssl_verify_mode + bundler + geminabox

Tags: ruby, ssl-certificate, bundler, gemfile, geminabox

I'm trying to set up a private geminabox server to hold some gems my project is developing. I have the server set up, with passenger nginx running geminabox as a rack app. I am able to bundle install pointing at the server without using SSL.

Since naked HTTP traffic is never ideal, I want to add SSL as well. To get a proof of concept working, I added an SSL cert and verified I could still see the geminabox front end with gem I have installed.

When I go back to my ruby project, I run a bundle install and get:

`Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://********.com/.`

`There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.`

Following the link the error message gave me, I decided to start by adding ~/.gemrc with the contents:

`:ssl_verify_mode: 0`

(not ideal, and not the permanent solution). Now I get:

`Fetching source index from https://***.com/`

`Resolving dependencies...`

`Could not verify the SSL certificate for 
https://***.com/quick/Marshal.4.8/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mswin32-60.gemspec.rz.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA
certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without
using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.`

My question is, how do I correctly set SSL verify to off in bundler? Is there another setting I should use? Thanks for any help you can give...

My system:

Ubuntu 14.04

Ruby 2.1.2

Bundler version 1.8.4

Answer (score 2):

Rather than answering how to disable validation (I'm not sure how or if it's possible, and I can't recommend it) here is how to specify a path to a custom CA certificate file, which is a more secure solution:

```
bundle config --global ssl_ca_cert /path/to/file.pem
```

Source http://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html#LIST-OF-AVAILABLE-KEYS

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it out and I got: `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: hostname "***********.com" does not match the server certificate (https://***********.com/specs.4.8.gz)` Looks like I need to do this the correct way from the start... Thank you for your help!